# Links are not clikable on live, but work in console

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

dear Stack Overflow community,
Sorry for bothering you with this question, but I couldn't find a cause, why the links that worked on my website stopped to work at some point (I mean email and about). I have checked the console: there were no errors,in css there was no z-index, or something that could overlap the elements. I would be thankful if someone could help me with this, here is the website:

https://changerz.education/

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi. Do you mean these links? - About ⋅ Contact ⋅ Terms of Use ⋅ Privacy Policy

Comment: Found a function that disabled anchor navigation. The case is closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are errors in the console.

It seems to me that your links do not work because of this code, which prohibits the following url:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart tap', 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Remove these two lines:

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

- bonus:

In the console you get the error: `e.indexOf is not a function at S.fn.init.S.fn.load`. And this error is caused by `jquery` event aliases. In your case, this is the `.load()` method, in the code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Do it like this and the error should be fixed:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
});
```